# Google drive API - ulpoad an audio blob converted in base64 string- drive.files.create method - File id not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, blob

I'm trying to sent an audio blob on some Google drive folder. To succeed I translate  blob in file before sending it.
I received since the starting an error :

> Error:  File not found.
>   code: 404,   errors:    [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'notFound',
>          message: 'File not found: 1aazd544z3FOCAsdOA5E7XcOaS3297sU.',
>          locationType: 'parameter',
>          location: 'fileId' } ] }

*progressive edit :* So far I have converted my audio blob in base64 string in order to ease the processing of my blob.

But, I fail always to write a file with my base 64 audio blob :

Here my driveApi.js :

```
 // request data from req.body
var data = req.body.data ; // data variable is presented in form of base64 string
var name = req.body.word ;
 (...)
 // WRITE FILE AND STORE IT IN BODY HEADER PROPERTY
  body: fs.writeFile((name + ".mp3"), data.substr(data.indexOf(',')+1), {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
    console.log('File created')
})
```

Comment: From your error message, it seems that the folder with folder ID is not found. The folder is in the Google Drive of the account which retrieved the token? If you cannot retrieve the folder information of the ID using files.get, how about try without ``parents: [folderId]``?

Comment: Hi Tanaike thank you for your answer. I just want to create a file. It works well when I retrieve the file from my directories so I assume the process works. My challenge is to create a file directly on server and send it to drive without writing it on my hard disk. 

I think I will work on the temporaries files maybe there is something interesting in this side

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you create the file to the folder of ``1aazdz3FOCADXUuOA5E7XcOaS3297sU`` as the upload from your local PC, it works fine. But when you create the file to the folder as the upload from the server, it doesn't work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yep that it. I chave tried without folder parameter it doesn't return error anymore but the file is not wrote neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three steps:** create a temporary file with your base64 data out of the drive.files.create function, then give this file a specific name -e.g. tempFile, also you can customize this name with a time value. After that, pass this file on a "fs.createReadStream" method to upload it on Google drive.

Some hints:

***Firstly -*** use path.join(__dirname, name + "-" + Date.now() +".ext" ) to create to file name

***Secondly -*** make this process asynchronously to avoid data flow conflict (trying to create file before file is created), so call the drive.files.create after having setting a fs.writeFile function.

***Thirdly -*** Destroy the tempFile after the operation has been done. It allows you to automatize the process.

I let you dive in the methods you need. But basically fs should do the job.

Again, be careful on the data flow and use callback to control it. Your code can crash just because the function gone up in a no-operational way.
Some links :

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

here an instance :

```
// datavalue = some time value 
fs.writeFile(
  path.join(__dirname, name + "-" + datevalues +".mp3" ),
  data.substr(data.indexOf(',')+1),
  {encoding: 'base64'},
  // callback
    function(err) {

        if(err){ console.log("error writting file : " + err)}
      console.log('File created')
      console.log("WRITTING") // control data flow
    fileCreate(name)
})

function fileCreate (name){
// upload file in specific folder
var folderId = "someID";
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': name + ".mp3" ,
  parents: [folderId]
}; console.log("MEDIA") // control data flow
var media = {
  mimeType: 'audio/mp3',
  body: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, name + "-" + datevalues +".mp3" ))
};
drive.files.create({
  auth: jwToken,
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
  }

  // make a callback to a deleteFile() function // I let you search for it
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? I'm not sure the condition of `blob` from reactApp.js. So could you please try to use this modification? In this modification, `file` or `blob` from reactApp.js are used.

#### Modified script :

```
var stream = require('stream'); // Added

module.exports.uploadFile = function(req){
 var file ;
  console.log("driveApi upload reached")
  function blobToFile(req){
    file = req.body.blob
    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    file.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    file.name = req.body.word;
    return file;
  }

var bufStream = new stream.PassThrough(); // Added
bufStream.end(file); // Or bufStream.end(### blob from reactApp.js ###) Added

console.log(typeof 42);
// upload file in specific folder
var folderId = "1aa1DD993FOCADXUDNJKLfzfXcOaS3297sU";
var fileMetadata = {
  "name": req.body.word,
  parents: [folderId]
}
var media = {
  mimeType: "audio/mp3",
  body: bufStream // Modified
}

drive.files.create({
  auth: jwToken,
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: "id"
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("File Id: ", file.id);
  }
  console.log("driveApi upload accomplished")
});
}
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tanaike. I have test it and improve my code in the same time // question editing

Comment: @Spiderman From your update, I could know that my answer didn't work. I wanted to know about the blob retrieved from ``data`` of ``var data = req.body.data``. By the way, for your updated script, I have 2 questions. 1. ``data`` of ``var data = req.body.data`` is a base64 value? 2. When the base64 value is converted to blob, can it be used as the correct blob?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks you for your answer, effectively I have add all theses improvements later in the day, by the time I have post it I didn't know that I will dive in. Yes is base64 value. Currently I have succeed to make my upload. Seems Google drive succeed to read it and my computer too, so I assume the process is relatively functional